# what is ... mysql_real_escape_string? dangerous?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why shouldn’t I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

hye, Can i use a code in php like this:

```
$s_username = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['username'])); 
$s_password = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['password']));
```

before this is use this

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
```

...because many said that mysql_real_escape_string is dangerous to use?

Comment: Who said that...? Perhaps they meant that you shouldn't use the mysql_* stack anymore and work with mysqli_* or PDO instead. The function itself is not *dangerous*, it's just deprecated.

Comment: Dangerous? In what way exactly?

Comment: use pdo or mysqli with prepared statements..

Comment: I'd not say explicitly dangerous if you know what you're doing, but `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and not very good to use in new code. PDO and MySQLi have functions that make the somewhat hard to use `mysql_real_escape_string` obsolete.

Comment: someone from stackoverflow members, he said this "noooooo dont use mysql_* functions its dangerous please. read up on prepared statements and start..."  is it true?.. i'm a newbie..

Comment: @RadsBelson: Yes, this is true. For new projects it is always recommended to use PDO or `mysqli_*` with prepared statements.

Comment: If you have to use the `mysql` extension, then `mysql_real_escape_string` is preferable to untainting variables yourself. It is currently thought to be safe (has been in production many years) though as others have said, it is unmaintained. Switch if you can!

Answer (score 1):

It's depreciated which means it's not being maintained, so if a security flaw is discovered, PHP developers aren't going to fix it. It's not dangerous though, it just escapes all bad characters that could be used for sql injection.

Use mysqli_* functions or PDO instead. Those actually are being maintained and are way more secure.

Comment: They are in fact dangerous -http://www.iodigitalsec.com/mysql_real_escape_string-wont-magically-solve-your-sql-injection-problems/